# Credential Provider with Azure AD Work account

Tags: credential-providers, windows-credential-provider

I have been building a credential provider in C++, I was able to make it work with azure ad by passing credentials and user with "azuread\username". Now If end user change its password using some other method, credential provider dont accept new password and it works on old password only.
Is there any way i can update credential cache in background and ask end user to reauthenticate with the new password?
Windows credential provider do work with new password

I have tried serializing the new password but it fails